# Web API 5.0.0-rc1 breaking default routes

Tags: asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

Before I updated from Web API `5.0.0-beta2` to `5.0.0-rc1` I could do something like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/test")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public TestString Get()
    {
        return new TestString { str = "HELLO WORLD" };
    }
}
```

so when I went to the URL `/api/v1/test` it would land on the `Get()` function.

After updating to Web API `5.0.0-rc1` I get a 404 when going to `/api/v1/test`

However, this works:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet("test")]
    public TestString Get()
    {
        return new TestString { str = "HELLO WORLD" };
    }
}
```

Can you explain why this doesn't work any longer?

** **EDIT** **
`[HttpGet("")]` works. Then it breaks on that `Get()` function.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but I believe the Http[Get, Post, etc] type attributes have had their routing properties removed.  This link hints at it:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2013/08/28/asp-net-web-api-attribute-based-routing.aspx

> be aware that most of the Attribute based Routing samples available
>   today on the web, is using old attribute like [PUT] or [HttpPut] which
>   is no longer supported on the latest bit (currently available from the
>   ASP.NET nightly build, http://www.myget.org/F/aspnetwebstacknightly/
>   ), those attributes ware replaced with [Route] attribute.

Please see https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets and https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1206.  Basically, the goal is to separate verb filters from attribute routing.

Comment: Thank you, but `[Route]` isn't working. However does `[HttpGet("")]` work. I think Microsoft doesn't know what they're gonna do.